# C# - How to disable context menu in window form?

Tags: c#-4.0

I created a context menu for my window form, whenever i do right click on the window, the context window will pop up. However, in some case i want to disable this context menu from popping up after i right click the mouse. Is there any way to disable/enable the whole context menu?

Answer (score 0):

```
contextMenuStrip1.Visible = false;
```

Comment: But I cannot find Visible in my context menu!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to remove the default right-click menu is to define your own (empty) menu:

```
myTextBox.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
```

This will, in one line, remove the default Windows right-click options. Understand that the keyboard shortcuts `(Ctrl-C, Ctrl-X, Ctrl-V, Ctrl-A, Ctrl-Z)` will all still work; you're not disabling the basic functionality, just the mouse-able access to it.

For a TextBox within a ContextMenu of another TextBox, it's a little trickier, but basically you can directly access the TextBox that is contained within the ToolStripItem, using the item's TextBox property. This property is a vanilla System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, like any other you'd have in your app:

```
myToolStripTextBox.TextBox.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may cancel context menu opening when some condition is fulfilled using the context menu opening event:

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
  e.Cancel = somecondition == true;
}
```